# Ubuntu 20.04 - How to automount a CIFS share if mounting during boot fails

Tags: 20.04, samba, fstab, automount, cifs

I'm trying to automatically mount a samba share residing on nas running openmediavault 5.6.12-1 and samba version 4.9.5-Debian on my desktop running Ubuntu 20.04.3.

After following the instructions in [the openmediavault forum](https://forum.openmediavault.org/index.php?thread/23489-ubunutu-18-04-how-to-automount-a-cifs/&postID=178599&highlight=fstab#post178599) and [the ubuntu community](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountCifsFstab) I added the following command to my fstab file:

```
//192.168.100.12/HomSpace /media/nasMounted cifs credentials=/root/.memoriaCredentials,uid=1000,gid=1000,noperm,rw,vers=3.0 0 0
```

When I execute `sudo mount -a` the share folder is mounted correctly without errors. Unfortunately, after rebooting the PC the folder is not mounted automatically. I haven't found any instructions on the internet suggesting a different and equally practicable way to mount a  cifs share folder and without any error in the log I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

What's wrong with the command that I added to the fstab? How can I automount the cifs share at boot?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: the only difference between your fstab entry and mine `//192.168.1.117/[NAS share_name] /media/NAS/GnV_Common cifs username=[name],password=[password],rw,uid=1000,gid=500` where it works perfectly well. I haven't included `vers=3.0` or `noperm` params. For exploration purposes, perhaps try editing those out to see what changes. I would do that by copy/paste the line, make your changes and and comment out the line(s) you need to suppress.

Comment: I mount shares through fstab as well; it works reliably. I have the `vers=3.0` parameter but instead of `noperm` I have `nofail`. Based on this and the comment by @24601, I suspect the problem is the `noperm` parameter.  Edit: I also don't have the `rw` parameter.

Comment: I removed all flags from the entry in the fstab: `//192.168.100.12/HomSpace /media/nasMounted cifs credentials=/root/.memoriaCredentials 0 0`  but without any improvement. When I click on the share though nautilus before executing `sudo mount -a` I get this error: Unable to access "nasMounted" mount: /media/nasMounted: operation permitted for root only. I suppose it has to do with the ownership of the hosting folder. Probably normal since I'm not root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the share will mount when you issue a `sudo mount -a` I suspect there is nothing wrong with your fstab declaration. It does suggest a timing issue. Linux is reading fstab before the network stack is up and operational so when it goes to mount the network share it fails.

2 possibilities are to turn this into a "mount on demand":

[1] Keep your current mount point but add two more options: `noauto,user`

```
//192.168.100.12/HomSpace /media/nasMounted cifs credentials=/root/.memoriaCredentials,uid=1000,gid=1000,noperm,rw,vers=3.0,noauto,user 0 0
```

When you boot your system the share will not mount but it will show up on the side panel of your file manager as a launcher. Click on it and it will go to fstab to see how to mount it then do so.

**EDIT**: *As pointed out below I should have made sure the credentials file was readable by the ordinary user for this method to work. Placing it under one's home directory would be a better choice.*

[2] Change your mount point and use a systemd automounter.

Mount point cannot be under your home directory or /media so I would suggest something like /mnt/nasMounted. Then add two options `noauto,x-systemd.automount`

```
//192.168.100.12/HomSpace /mnt/nasMounted cifs credentials=/root/.memoriaCredentials,uid=1000,gid=1000,noperm,rw,vers=3.0,noauto,x-systemd.automount 0 0
```

This works by accessing the /mnt/nasMounted mount point. Either by you directly through the file manager, or by any application, or by any other process. Pretty much anything accessing that mount point will trigger a mount all without your intervention.

Either way after you edit fstab run these two commands to make systemd happy:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload

sudo systemctl restart remote-fs.target
```

Comment: I was also suspecting that the problem had to do with a timing issue, like reported in the [Troubleshooting section at Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently). But your explanation and proposed solutions are far better. I already tried the solution [1], which works beautifully with one exception: when I clicked on the share from the file manager,I get this error `error 13(Permission denied) opening credential file /root/.memoriaCredentials`. Since both the folder and the file are restricted to root, I created a new credential file in my home folder. Better solution?

Comment: I should have asked about the /root/.memoriaCredentials file to make sure it was readable to you. I got sloppy.